# Returning a blade component from a controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I'm running Laravel 7, and I wonder if it is possible to return a rendered Blade component from a controller, just like you would with a view. I can return the view of the component like the following.

```
return View::make('components.some-view');
```

However, I do not have access to any of the data or methods inside the SomeView component class. If I try to use a variable defined in the component, I receive an undefined variable error.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it works for me in Laravel 8

for example I have **`App\View\Components\Form\Button`** **component**

```
<?php 
   class Button extends Component{
       public $variable1;
       public $variable2;

       public function __construct($variable1, $variable2){
            $this->variable1 = $variable1;
            $this->variable2 = $variable2;
       }

       public function render(){
             // return view('view_component_name'); 
       }
   }
?>
```

& I wants to render that component in controller without view layout
then I can do like this

```
<?php
  use App\View\Components\Form\Button;

  class TestController extends Controller{

     public function index(Request $request)

        $obj = new Button($variable1, $variable2);
        $obj->render()->with($obj->data());
     }
  }
?>
```

** data function include methods, properties and attributes of Component.

I hope this one helps to you

Comment: why my answer got negative votes? my answer is working example. I use this way in my project for render specific component view with calling main view or any extend view, then it is very useful.

Comment: don't forget to call "return" at the end of method

Comment: @HassanElshazlyEida ya, but its depends on requirement what you need to return like json response or view page response. so I doesn't mentioned it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can render a blade component from your controller using `view` function:

```
//first parameter = Path of your component
//second argument = All your variables that your component receive 

$html = view('components.yourComponentName', ['x-variable' => $value]);
return $html;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create object of component in controller like

```
$com = new SomeComponent($variable1, $variable2);

//call the render function
$comHtml = $com->render();
```

Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score -1):

Use YourDirectory\some-view;

$controllerObject =  new some-view;

$controllerObject -> variable;